# I want to connect from composer to vm with ssh --internal-ip but I get a permission error

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I want to connect from composer to vm with ssh --internal-ip but I get a permission error.
I tested ssh with vm and composer using the same VPC / subnet and it looks like this.
What are the possible problems? And how can I try to make ssh successful?

### DAG

```
"""A liveness prober dag for monitoring composer.googleapis.com/environment/healthy."""
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'in-ssh',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='liveness monitoring dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))

# priority_weight has type int in Airflow DB, uses the maximum.
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='in-ssh',
    bash_command='gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "asia-northeast1-a" "dev-testserver01" --internal-ip --project "project"',
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    priority_weight=2**31-1)
```

error-log

```
[2021-04-01 03:12:52,404] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - Updating project ssh metadata...
[2021-04-01 03:13:09,570] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - .....................................................................................Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/project].
[2021-04-01 03:13:10,257] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - ...done.
[2021-04-01 03:13:10,301] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
[2021-04-01 03:13:10,573] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - Warning: Permanently added 'compute.6676320815635940303' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[2021-04-01 03:13:10,665] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - airflow@192.168.10.8: Permission denied (publickey).
[2021-04-01 03:14:07,028] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.
[2021-04-01 03:14:07,654] {bash_operator.py:162} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2021-04-01 03:14:07,697] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - Bash command failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `BashOperator()` to ssh to your VM instance, use `ComputeEngineSSHHook()` and pass your parameters to this method. For reference on this method see this [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/compute_ssh/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook).

You can refer to this github link [example_compute_ssh.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_compute_ssh.py). This shows how to use `ComputeEngineSSHook()` to connect to different VM setups.

Here is a snippet from the [github link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_compute_ssh.py):

```
import os
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh import ComputeEngineSSHHook
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator

GCP_PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT_ID', 'example-project')
GCE_ZONE = os.environ.get('GCE_ZONE', 'europe-west2-a')
GCE_INSTANCE = os.environ.get('GCE_INSTANCE', 'target-instance')

vm_ssh = SSHOperator(
    task_id="vm_ssh",
    ssh_hook=ComputeEngineSSHHook(
        instance_name=GCE_INSTANCE,
        zone=GCE_ZONE,
        project_id=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
        use_oslogin=True,
        use_iap_tunnel=False,
        use_internal_ip=True, // include this line if you are using internal ip
    ),
    command="echo vm_ssh",
)
```

Comment: I get a `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud'` error